# Adding a list as a column to a Data Frame on python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame and lists I generated from some for loops using the values on the data frame. However I would like this lists to become columns of the data frame.

```
archivo=pd.read_csv('winequalityN.csv')  #this is my file
Y=archivo['quality'] #a column from the data frame  

y1=[]
for y in Y:
    if y < 7:
        y1.append(0)
    else:
        y1.append(1)
y2=[]
for y in Y:
    if 5<= y < 7:
        y2.append(1)
    else:
        y2.append(0)
y3=[]
for y in Y:
    if y < 5:
        y3.append(1)
    else:
        y3.append(0)
```

I would like to make a column on my dataframe for each list.

Comment: Just a neat trick. You can simplify some of the construction: `y1 = [int(y >= 7) for y in Y]`

Comment: I'm unclear on what the goal is. Are you looking for something along the lines of `archivo['new col'] = archivo['quality'].ge(7).astype(int)` (for the first 1)? Do you need the lists for something else later? Are you adding the lists to cells in the column or dynamically building new columns?

Comment: My goal is to add y1, y2 and y3 as columns of archivo. I'm just unclear on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

to simplify the data, say data is the 3 lists of numbers

```
data = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

would be same as saying `data = [y1,y2,y3]`. To pivot that is fast with this method.

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*data)]
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

so you can just dump that to a DF

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in zip(*data)])
   0  1   2
0  1  5   9
1  2  6  10
2  3  7  11
3  4  8  12
>>>
```